# Cron job of new user high CPU usage

Tags: 18.04, server, cron, lts, administration

I have a fresh (3 weeks) install of Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS and about a week in I created 2 new users. If the cron systemd service is running, something is making my cpu really hurt, cause the load went from about 6% straight to 60% occupying 4 threads in total.
[Grafana dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKhea.png) when I start cron.

How do I find out if I am victim of a mining exploit? Could it be something else?

Comment: Post the output of the command `top` in your question (use "edit"). It will not only reveal the high processor use, but also indicate what processes are responsible.

Comment: @vanadium unfortunately that won't do much. it just says `./cron` with a CPU usage of about 400%